# What's difference between "Total request time" and "Summary: exec time" in Grafana Query inspector?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I use Grafana explore to query logs from loki.
There is "Query inspector" function.

What is difference between "Total request time" and "Summary: exec time" in Query inspector?

[image]

Comment: I can only assume *Total request time* is a stat from Grafana itself. Basically how long whole query execution took, between passing query into data source plugin and receiving data. And *Summary: exec time* since it's in the Data source stats section is probably internal stat from data source itself. for example RDBMS (or at least Oracle) knows how long specifically query evaluation took, outside of networking time to receive and send data.

Comment: But I cannot find and documentation stating this. Nor code reference that could imply such. So it's only my educated guess.

Comment: Yeah, I think the same as you. But If so then i'm shocked that the difference is so big. Because for this example I used really simple query. Why did "grafana" add so much overload that is the question.

Comment: it's not necessarily Grafana who is spending all this time. It might be networking, or actual data fetch withing your data source.